# Django_filters have initial value only when ?page=1 is present

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-filter, django-tables2

I have the a view, `AccoutList`, which is trying to render a django_table2 table. The view's source code:

```
class AccountList(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    model = Account
    table_class = AccountTable
    template_name = 'accounts/account_list.html'
    context_table_name = 'object_list'
    ordering = ['vps']

    filterset_class = AccountFilter
```

This view is currently using this filterset (from django_filters):

```
import django_filters
from accounts.models import Account

class AccountFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['is_suspended', 'is_abandoned']

    is_suspended = django_filters.BooleanFilter(name='is_suspended', initial='False')
    is_abandoned = django_filters.BooleanFilter(name='is_abandoned', initial='False')

    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # if filterset is bound, use initial values as defaults
        if data is not None:
            # get a mutable copy of the QueryDict
            data = data.copy()

            for name, f in self.base_filters.items():
                initial = f.extra.get('initial')

                # filter param is either missing or empty, use initial as default
                if not data.get(name) and initial:
                    data[name] = initial

        super().__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
```

Using this template:

```
{% if filter %}
    <form action="" method="get" class="form form-inline">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
{% endif %}

{% render_table object_list %}

{% endblock %}
```

This is my from my urls.py

```
path('', login_required(AccountList.as_view())),
```

When I visit my page, `127.0.0.1:8000`, I see that the filters are not set:
[image]

But then if i do `127.0.0.1:8000?page=1`, I see the filters are initialized properly:

[image]

### What is causing my filters to not have default value when I don't have page=1 appended to my url?

Answer (score 0):

Initial value of `BooleanFilter` should be boolean, not string:

```
is_suspended = django_filters.BooleanFilter(name='is_suspended', initial=False)
is_abandoned = django_filters.BooleanFilter(name='is_abandoned', initial=False)
```